# Akka-HTTP compilation error using custom requireParam() directive

Tags: scala, akka-http

I developed custom generic directive, which will provide param of given type, if it exists, or else reject with my custom exception.

```
import akka.http.scaladsl.common.NameReceptacle
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.Directives._
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.directives.ParameterDirectives.ParamDefAux
import akka.http.scaladsl.server.{Directive1, Route}

class MyCustomException(msg: String) extends Exception(msg)

def requireParam[T](name: NameReceptacle[T])
                   (implicit pdef: ParamDefAux[NameReceptacle[T], Directive1[T]]): Directive1[T] =
  parameter(name).recover { _ =>
    throw new MyCustomException(s"${name.name} is missed!")
  }
```

It works ok, if I want to create route, using two parameters, for example:

```
val negSumParams: Route =
  (requireParam("param1".as[Int]) & requireParam("param2".as[Int])) {
    (param1, param2) =>
      complete((-param1-param2).toString)
  }
```

But if I try to use exactly one parameter, this doesn't compile:

```
val negParamCompilationFail: Route =
  requireParam("param".as[Int]) {
    param => // scalac complains about missing type param here
      complete((-param).toString)
  }
```

If I use it with `pass` directive, it works:

```
val negParamWithPass: Route =
  (pass & requireParam("param".as[Int])) { // this pass usage looks hacky
    param =>
      complete((-param).toString)
  }
```

If I write `requireParam()` return type explicitly, it works too:

```
val negParamWithExplicitType: Route =
  (requireParam("param".as[Int]): Directive1[Int]) { // DRY violation
    param =>
      complete((-param).toString)
  }
```

Why do I need these tricks? Why can't it work just with `requireParam("param".as[Int])`?

Scala version 2.12.1, Akka-HTTP 10.0.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Johannes from Lightbend answered to this question here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/akka-user/NmQvcrz5sJg Answer is:

> You discovered one of the reasons for the magnet pattern. If you use
>   `requireParam("param".as[Int]) { abc => ... }` then the `{ abc => }`
>   block is mistaken as the implicit argument of `requireParam`. So,
>   either you are ok with that and require users to use extra parentheses
>   (`(requireParam("param".as[Int])) { abc => ... }`) or you use the
>   magnet pattern at this level as well. You can read about the magnet
>   pattern on the old spray blog
>   (http://spray.io/blog/2012-12-13-the-magnet-pattern/) or just look
>   into akka-http sources.
>
> A better way to implement the feature would be just to use the
>   existing implementation ;) and install a custom rejection handler that
>   produces whatever output you would like. See
>   https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/10.0.10/scala/http/routing-dsl/rejections.html#customizing-rejection-handling
>   for how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

This error happens due to the Directive companion object apply method. IT allows to create a Route from a function with parameter (T => Route) => Route:

```
object Directive {

  /**
   * Constructs a directive from a function literal.
   */
  def apply[T: Tuple](f: (T ⇒ Route) ⇒ Route): Directive[T] =
    new Directive[T] { def tapply(inner: T ⇒ Route) = f(inner) }

}
```

But the T parameter must be a tuple. In your case, the compiler can not build the Route. Your **requireParam("param".as[Int])** returns a Directive1[Int] so the apply method doesn´t work because Int is not a Tuple.

To make this work you shoul use tapply method directly:

```
(requireParam("param1".as[Int])).tapply((param1) =>
    complete((-param1._1).toString))
```

and

```
  val negSumParams2: Route =
    (requireParam("param1".as[Int]) & requireParam("param2".as[Int])).tapply {
      case (param1, param2) =>
        complete((-param1-param2).toString)
    }
```

So it seems that every Directive tries to convert its param to TupleX. For example:

**path("order" / IntNumber) returns a Directive[Tuple1[Int]]** instead of Directive1[Int]. In your case requireParam("param1".as[Int]) returns Directive1[Int]

Maybe there is a better solution and to avoid tapply

Comment: `Directive1[Int]` is just an alias for `Directive[Tuple1[Int]]`. Also, this compiles:

`val dir = requireParam("param1".as[Int]); dir { param1 => complete((-param).toString)`

So, seems like you're not right about explanation :(

Though, thanks anyway for suggesting another option with using `tapply`.